# Auto logout rdp sessions

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012-r2, group-policy

I have a need to logout certain rdp sessions (superadmin account) after 15 minutes of inactivity. if someone forgets to disconnect a session from one of the windows servers and a password changes overnight, it wont lock the account.  I have found a group policy setting for this (end a disconnected session in remote desktop services) but i only want to apply it to the super admin account, is this possible by just adding the super admin to the gp permission.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You describe the condition as *if someone forgets to disconnect a session* and you are applying *End a disconnected session* setting on your [Remote Desktop Services Sessions](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754272(v=ws.11).aspx). First you need to understand the difference between two settings:

> **End a disconnected session**
>
> Specify the maximum amount of time that a
> disconnected user session is kept active on the RD Session Host
> server. If you specify "Never," the user's disconnected session is
> maintained for an unlimited time. When a session is in a disconnected
> state, running programs are kept active even though the user is no
> longer actively connected.
>
> **Idle session limit**
>
> Specify the maximum amount of time that an active
> Remote Desktop Services session can be idle (without user input)
> before the session is automatically disconnected or ended. The user
> receives a warning two minutes before the session is disconnected or
> ended, which allows the user to press a key or move the mouse to keep
> the session active.

It sounds like you need the latter, instead.

Both of these setting can be set in *Computer Configuration* or *User Configuration*.  As you want to apply this only on specific user(s), you need to use the settings on **User Configuration > Policies > Administrative Templates > Windows Components > Remote Desktop Services > Remote Desktop Session Host > Session Time Limits**.

As always, you can apply a [GPO](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh147307(v=ws.10).aspx) only to specific users if they are on a separate [OU container](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc978003.aspx).